# How do I change image on tkinter button, after initial load?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a UI in Pythons with tkinter. I have a button with an image, and I want to change the image when it is clicked.

The button is simple enough:

```
self.otherImage = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(self.imagesFolder, "image2.png"))

self.image=tkinter.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(self.imagesFolder, "image1.png"))
self.button = tkinter.Button(self.mainWindow, image=self.image, command=lambda: [self.clicked()])
```

And the clicked function, as well:

```
def clicked(self):
    self.button.image=self.otherImage
```

But the image in the GUI never changes. I've tried swapping the images and see the same behavior, either image will display on initial load, neither will load on click.

I feel like I'm missing something simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all `Widget` options, via `.keys()`.

```py
#replace `DesiredWidget` with the existing widget that you want info from
print(tk.DesiredWidget(None).keys())
```

If we do that for `tk.Button`, `"image"` is one of the keys present. This means you can do any of the following:

```py
#set
button['image'] = the_image
button.configure(image=the_image)

#get
the_image = button['image']
the_image = button.cget('image')
```

Whether you call a method or key the option, `tk` surfs through a number of branches to eventually set your desired option. You can go directly to the ultimate command by calling it manually.

```py
#self._w already exists, you just need to supply `the_image`
self.tk.call(self._w, 'configure', '-image', the_image)
```

The above info can be helpful if you wanted to do something like the below. By changing your `Button` to `ImageButton` the rest of your code would work, and get directly to the point of the call.

```
import tkinter as tk

class ImageButton(tk.Button):
    @property
    def image(self):
        try: return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-image')
        except tk.TclError: return None

    @image.setter
    def image(self, img):
        try: self.tk.call(self._w, 'configure', '-image', img)
        except tk.TclError: pass #replace pass with something meaningful
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried calling `button.configure(image=<new image>)` instead of assign photo obj directly and the button is able to change the image as opposed to assign the image obj directly

```
import tkinter as tk

otherImage = tk.PhotoImage(file=photo1)
image = tk.PhotoImage(file=photo)

def clicked():
    button.configure(image=otherImage)

button = tk.Button(root, image=image, command=lambda: [clicked()])
button.pack(side = tk.TOP)

root.mainloop()
```